# If $f$ is a homeomorphism from an open subset $U$ of $R^n$ to a subset $V$ of $R^n$

Tags: general-topology

If $f$ is a homeomorphism from an open subset $U$ of $R^n$ to a subset $V$ of $R^n$, is $V$ also open in $R^n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is [Brouwer's Invariance of Domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain) Theorem.

Answer (score -3):

Edited to add (thanks commenters): if the domain of $f$ is only $U$ then you do in fact need the fancy theorem. I read the question too fast and assumed $f$ was a homeomorphism from $\Bbb{R}^2$ to itself. I will leave this answer because the comments on it are valuable.

It needs nothing as fancy as a big named theorem. A homeomorphism is a continuous bijection with continuous inverse. A function $f$ is continuous if and only if the preimage of an open set is always open. So you have these facts:

$f^{-1}$ is continuous, and

$V$ is the preimage of an open set $U$ under $f^{-1}$.

Thus $V$ is open.

Comment: This is simply wrong, and a common misconception regarding the invariance of domain. Your argument allows you to say that $V$ is open **in $V$**, not in $\mathbb{R}^n$. For instance, take the inclusion of the closed interval in $\mathbb{R}^2$. It is a homeomorphism with its image, but the image is clearly not open in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: If your argument were correct, then it would be correct for all topological spaces and also for maps between different topological spaces.  With that it mind, you can find counterexamples everywhere.  A nice counterexample is $V$ any classical sequences space $\ell_1, \ell_2, \dots, \ell_\infty$, and $f:V \to V$ the one sided shift $(x_1, x_2, \dots) \mapsto (0, x_1, x_2, \dots)$.  Then $f$ is an isometry of $V$ onto its range, hence a homeomorphism onto its range, but the range is not open in $V$.